# How to fix memory leak issues?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-glide, android-memory

I'm making an android app that has multiple fragments, activities, and Multiple Recyclerviews, and images that are loaded in recycler view from the firebase using glide.
My problem is my app is very lagging.
When I used the profiler to monitor the app's memory consumption, my app's memory consumption is increasing too high. (say, my app takes 60 MB at first 2 sec, then 100, 200, 350,.... up to it looks 2 GBs of memory).
I know it is a potential memory leak. But I don't know how to fix this. Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add some code how did you load the image to recylerviews?

Answer (score 1):

The first approach is to profile your app from Android Studio ( profile 'app' button -> choose MEMORY from the dropdown list -> double click to expand -> and examine your allocations.

Which component seems to burden the heap?

There is also LeakCanary to do the job for you: https://github.com/square/leakcanary

Comment: Okay thankyou! I'm getting the memory issues when switching between fragments. so suggest me a good way to use multiple fragments(like in instagram home page)

Comment: Well the general concept to save on memory is to keep in memory only the fragments/components being used. For example if you are using a ViewPager you could switch to FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter. Another way is to reuse layouts that are already on the UI cache. It depends on your implementation. If nothing works you will have to rethink your architecture. Some useful info: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/

Comment: actually today I found one thing. The memory Leak occurs in Android 6.0 but not in 7.0 and above. What may be the reason?

Comment: Hmmm, I am sorry but it is too broad. If you are using any external libs check that they don't have any known issues (github) with different Android versions. But do more testing, make sure it wasn't random, maybe Android 7 has better memory management that hides the issue.